# Jenkins pass the variable value from Groovy script to Email Plugin

Tags: email, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to send one variable value from a groovy script to email plugin, so that the value will be part of email body.

I am using `EnvInject` for this, and my groovy script is as below

```
import hudson.model.*
def pa = new ParametersAction([
  new StringParameterValue("MYVAR", "BAR")
])
build.addAction(pa)
```

And in my email step in `Default content` section i am trying to get the value of `MYVAR` using the syntax `${ENV(var: "MYVAR")}`

But in the email i am getting blanks. Please suggest what i am missing.

Comment: how are you exposing the parameter from the groovy script to the EnvInject plugin?

Comment: There is an option to run the groovy script in EnvInject .. I am running the above script in that

Answer (score 0):

Once you are really sure you env. variable is set. You can do this:

```
mail bcc: '', body: "Job name: ${env.JOB_NAME} ", cc: '', charset: 'UTF-8', from: '', mimeType: 'text/html', replyTo: '', subject: "ERROR CI: Project name -> ${env.JOB_NAME}", to: "foo@foo.com";
```

Please, note you can access variable like this:

```
"${env.VAR_NAME}"
```